# Overflow: hidden not working older versions of Android Webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, webview

I've tried researching all day to find a solution to this issue and I'm having absolutely no issues.

My APP uses a WebView to display some text in rows and I've always just used the simple CSS overflow:hidden to hide text that may "run off" past the height of a div etc.  However, I'm finding that older phones back to around API 15 etc that aren't running the newest version of WebView 4.4 Android version, doesn't support overflow:hidden at all.  At least from what I am seeing for myself and reading.

Anyone know a solution around this to fix it so it can still work in the web view itself?  Maybe a java-script method or something that we use to use in "ancient" times before using overflow:hidden or something?

I thought about maybe trying to programmatically trimming the text down to a specific amount of characters, but we all know that like ARIAL has different sizes for each letter so trying to do this by the total amount of characters itself can trim it wayy to early etc.